# Creating a Macro, that allows me to deleted dupilcation in other columns "only if" the cell beside contains the exact same number

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that will allows me to deleted dupilcation "only if" the cell beside contains the exact same number.

Example:

Range will be P15:Q34

```
        P       Q
Row 15  8.22    8.22

Row 16  16.33   32.22

Row 17  25.66   25.66

.
.
. and so on
```

As you can see, I have duplication in Q15 and Q17. I would like to keep the all the information in P columns and any Q cells (like Q16) but only delete the duplcation. Can someone help me please with this macro?

Comment: First of all.. where is your code ... as in, what have you tried so far? Secondly, so you want row 15 and 17 to be deleted completely?

Comment: Do you want **Q15** to be cleared or do you want the cell deleted and all the values below it to move up??

Comment: I do not have a code yet since I really do not have a clue how to make this. Yes, I would like anything in Q to be remove if there is duplications. Just deleting the information not the entire row or cell. I have seen quite a few examples of ones deleting the entire row but nothing with just deleting the information inside the current cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
Sub Test()
    For Each Cell In Sheets("New Summary").Range("P15:Q34")
        If Cell.Value = Cell.Offset(0, 1) Then
            Cell.Offset(0, 1) = ""
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I would personally prefer @pnuts solution.

Comment: Thank you! One thing...if I have changed my sheet name to "New Summary" how would that be used in the code?

Comment: Replace index number with sheet name ... `Sheets("New Summary")`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is easy without VBA. In another column (I suggest in Row15) put:

```
=IF(P15=Q15,"",Q15)
```

and copy down to suit. Select the results and paste Special Values into Q15.

Comment: Thank you! I would, but I already have a massive IF statement in that cell or cells. It is more for after and reviewing the final product. I like @Pankaj Jaju macro, only thing is...if I have changed my sheet name to "New Summary" how would that be used in the code below?